# Number of indexes in an Array

Tags: php, arrays, count, indexing, size

I wish to count the number of indexes my new array have.

Below is a screenshot of my code. The values within the violet box is my output. My $High array lists down the values from my accu.php and new.php (within the require).

Now, want to list the unique values of my $High array using my new array, named $result. Then, I want to count the indexes of my $result array. I have tried the count() and sizeof() function and it still displays 9 as seen below.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
require("accu.php");
require("new.php");

$High = array ($Accu_High1,$Accu_High2,$Accu_High3,$Accu_High4,$Accu_High5,$new1,$new2,$new3,$new4,$new5,$new6,$new7,$new8,$new9,$new0);

$result = array_unique($High); // remove similar
$count = sizeof($result); //count

for ($int = 0; $int<=14; $int++)
{
    echo "<b>$int</b> $High[$int]<br>";
}

echo "<br><br><br><b>$count</b>";
?>
```

And below is my output:

```
0 22
1 32
2 33
3 32
4 32
5 30
6 31
7 31
8 31
9 30
10 23
11 30
12 31
13 30
14 30



9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Array indexes are unique**. So `count($array)` is all you need to count the *'indexes'*.

But, I'm not sure this question display minimal understanding of PHP arrays. The PHP online manual or a book are the answer here. Like how `foreach` works and such trivial matters.

**So use `var_dump` against your array and analyze the output**. Then see what's actually going on. There's many array functions/functionality and you should know them.

Comment: Here's my output using your var_dump.

array(6) { [0]=> string(2) "22" [1]=> string(2) "32" [2]=> string(2) "33" [5]=> string(2) "30" [6]=> string(2) "31" [10]=> string(2) "23" } 0 22
1 32
2 33
3 32
4 32
5 30
6 31
7 31
8 31
9 30
10 23
11 30
12 30
13 31
14 31

Comment: @coding.bird Why do you create the `$result` variable if you don't use it? In your print function, you use the same old variable that hasn't gone through the `array_unique`. Are you aware of that?